# Reference to other variable

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to do some minimal app for myself and I have a little problem with selected path. I have the following code:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
{


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }               
    private void FilesCountNumberShow_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Try to count nu,ber of files in folder
        int fCount = Directory.GetFiles(count_path, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length;
        FilesCountNumber_Label.Content = "Files in folder: " + fCount;


    }

    private void SelectFolderPath_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // These code is for open File Dialog and choose older path as count_path
        var SelectFolderPath_Dialog = new WinForms.FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (SelectFolderPath_Dialog.ShowDialog() == WinForms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string count_path = SelectFolderPath_Dialog.SelectedPath;
            MessageBox.Show(count_path);

        }

    }
}
```

}

How can I reference the variable `count_path` in

```
 int fCount = Directory.GetFiles(count_path, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length;
```

I have information that it isn't exist (I think is locla variable in `SelectFolderPath_button_Click` right? How can I set it global?

I do something that. I add `string count_path { get; set; }` there:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
     string count_path { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

and modify

```
 private void SelectFolderPath_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var SelectFolderPath_Dialog = new WinForms.FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (SelectFolderPath_Dialog.ShowDialog() == WinForms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            count_path = SelectFolderPath_Dialog.SelectedPath;

            MessageBox.Show(count_path);

        }

    }
```

Is this good solution or should it be otherwise done?

Comment: You have count_path defined inside a module.  define the variable outside the module so more than one module can access the variable.

Comment: Your solution will work, though I'd rather introduce a private field instead of a property.

Comment: Some examples? Little hint?

Comment: @jdweng: There is no such thing as a "module" in C#. If he only wants to use this field inside his class, then felix-b's recommendation is correct.

Comment: @Arlid: What felix-b meant is to simply replace `string count_path { get; set; }` by `string count_path;`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a property instead of a field. In fact, [Code Lens in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/find-code-changes-and-other-history-with-codelens?view=vs-2019) works for properties and not fields, so in one respect, a property is better to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Store the selected path in a private field and validate that it has been set:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string count_path;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FilesCountNumberShow_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(count_path))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must select a folder first!");
        }
        else
        {
            // Try to count nu,ber of files in folder
            int fCount = Directory.GetFiles(count_path, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length;
            FilesCountNumber_Label.Content = "Files in folder: " + fCount;
        }
    }

    private void SelectFolderPath_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // These code is for open File Dialog and choose older path as count_path
        var SelectFolderPath_Dialog = new WinForms.FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (SelectFolderPath_Dialog.ShowDialog() == WinForms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            count_path = SelectFolderPath_Dialog.SelectedPath;
            MessageBox.Show(count_path);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  //add assembly reference System.Windows.Forms
   private void SelectFolderPath_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
           using (var SelectFolderPath_Dialog = new   System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog())
           {
                if (SelectFolderPath_Dialog.ShowDialog() ==   System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                   {
                       string count_path = SelectFolderPath_Dialog.SelectedPath;
                   MessageBox.Show(count_path);

              }
           }
          }
```